# maintaining scroll bar position using javascript/jquery (jqgrid)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a problem with regards to maintaining the `scroll position` of my `jqgrid`.

Here is the objective of my program:

1. First, I click on the row.
2. After clicking on the row, a form will pop-up.
3. After updating record, the user will then close the form.
4. The jqgrid will reload.
5. After the jqgrid reloads, it will select the "last selected item"

I have no problem with these steps (1-5)

My problem is that if I have extensive rows for example 500 rows. It will display the scroll bars on the side of the jgrid.

What I want to do is to maintain the scroll position of the scroll bars using Javascript or jQuery. How do I do this?

I tried to use this, on loadcomplete event

```
var scrollPosition = 0;
                scrollPosition = jQuery("#jqgrid").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollTop(scrollPosition);
                jQuery("#jqgrid").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollTop(scrollPosition);
```

but it doest give me the value of the scroll position

Comment: "It will display the scroll bars on the side of the jgrid. 
What I want to do is to maintain the scroll position of the scroll bars using javascript or jquery." - so you want to control scroll position (begin/end of the page) or scroll bar position itself?

Comment: Here: If I click on row 250, suppose that the scroll bars is on the middle, after the grid reloads. The scroll bars will be positioned on the middle.

Comment: Look at [this link](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2010/01/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin/) or you can use jQuery scrollTo plugin.

Comment: Is the #element is the name of the grid?

Comment: Yes. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yx2aK/)

Answer (score 0):

See . [this fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/yx2aK/) based on [this article](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2010/01/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin/)

```
<input type="submit" id="button"/>
<div id="div1"> </div>


$("#button").click(function() {
 $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $("#div1").offset().top
 }, 2000);
 });
```

Comment: if im using jqgrid. How will i implement this?

Comment: Make your own jsfiddle to let me see your code. I can't do everything for you. I can try to change your fiddle to help you.